# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings?

Tags: java, mongodb

Website says 4.11.1 is compatible with java 8. I cannot upgrade my java version. Is there any way to fix this problem?

```java
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

...             
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
    .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(uri))                                                       
    .serverApi(serverApi)
    .build(); 

// Create a new client and connect to the server
try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings)) { 
...
```

error in the try(...){

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings`

this is my code, It is adapted straight from the codesample on the connect via drivers page on atlas. thanks in advance!

Comment: I vote it's not the whole error message